# Comparing PC and PLS regression performance on the test data depending on the number of components

Tags: regression, pca, partial-least-squares, out-of-sample

[image][image]I am performing PLS regression but have noticed that the R2 between predicted and measured values for the test set decreases with increasing the number of components. If I do principal components regression, as one would expect, R2 increases with increasing the number of components. Does this signal I'm doing something wrong somewhere? What are principal components in PLS at all? Could it be that the higher PCs in my PLS analysis introduce more noise than signal?

Here is a snippet of R code to better illustrate what I'm doing (data file is too big to upload):

PCA regression:

```
library("pls")
library("caret")
for (x in 1:70)
{
y_test <- test[, 3]
testx = test[,5:length(test)-1]
pcr_model <- pcr(as.matrix(train["affinity"]) ~ ., data = train[,5:length(train)-1], scale = TRUE, validation = "CV")
pcr_pred <- predict(pcr_model, testx, ncomp = x)
print (cor(pcr_pred, y_test)^2)
}
```

This behaves as one would expect - R2 increases with the number of components. If I do PLS by using the plsr function rather than pcr, however, R2 is highest with only a few components and progressively decreases from then on. How could that be?

PLS regression:

```
library("pls")
library("caret")
for (x in 1:70)
{
y_test <- test[, 3]
testx = test[,5:length(test)-1]
pcr_model <- plsr(as.matrix(train["affinity"]) ~ ., data = train[,5:length(train)-1], scale = TRUE, validation = "CV")
pcr_pred <- predict(pcr_model, testx, ncomp = x)
print (cor(pcr_pred, y_test)^2)
}
```

Comment: With PCR, the R2 on the test set usually has a peak at some number of PCs and does not increase all the way. Why do you think that one "would expect" the latter?

Comment: Possibly due to overfitting. I am not sure if the behaviour I observe with PLSR is unusual though.

Comment: But you said you are plotting the results on the test set? Why overfitting then?

Comment: The test and training sets are completely non-overlapping but similar in composition. I don't want to be describing 60 data points with 50 components. My concern is about the PLSR. Do you know if this behaviour is typical?

Comment: I would expect that both PCR and PLSR should exhibit overfitting and hence R2 on the test set should decrease with the number of components as on your second plot. So yes, second plot is typical. But the first plot is strange.